# how to write a command line to a file in c

Tags: c

I'm having issues with writing this command line to a file and it's suppose to output to the screen. To me, my code looks like it should work but I'm at a complete loss (this is my first time programming in C)

Print one line describing your program

Open the first parameter as a file for writing. If no parameter is provided, write to the stdout handle

Using a loop, save the contents of the array of string pointers passed as a parameter to the main function into the file open for writing. This is usually the variable named argv.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    printf("Output supplying 'multiple arguments' to this program");

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "w"); //Write to file
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
           fp = stdout;
    }

    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
           fprintf(fp, argv[i]);
    }

    printf("The number of arguments printed %d", argc);

    return 0;
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should not risk using user-input as `printf()` format strings.  Use `fprintf(fp, "%s\n", argv[i])` to print each argument on its own line (unless the argument itself contains newlines, in which case it will be spread over many lines).  Or use spaces between arguments.  Don't forget to end the output lines with newlines.  Don't forget to close the file.

Comment: How are you supposed distinguish between `argv[1]` - the "first parameter" - and the array of strings?

Comment: You rather notably aren't saying anything about *how* this fails. Compile-time issue? Runtime crash? Provide the actual error!

Comment: You've failed to explain the problem here. *I'm having issues* is not a meaningful problem description unless you explain what *issues* you're having. We can't see your screen from here. What *specific* problem are you having with the code you've posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use dynamic format strings in C. This opens you up to an extensive set of bugs, several of them security-sensitive. Instead, pass a format string that indicates your intent, like so:

```
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
       fprintf(fp, "%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you still have open issues, please edit your question to have enough information to solve them (explaining the actual problem that brought you here). If you don't, feel free to click the check box indicating that this answers your problem.